# How to make TestNG @DataProvider which returns several objects returns only one?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have following `@DataProvider`:

```
@DataProvider(name = "CredentialsProvider", parallel = true)
public static Object[][] credentialsProvider() {

    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < login.size(); i++) {
        credentials[i] = new Object[] {login.get(i)[0], password.get(i)[0]};
    }
    return credentials;
}
```

It used to generate credentials for test which are run in parallel mode:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "CredentialsProvider")
public void Login (String login, String password)
```

But sometimes I want to use the same `@DataProvider` in a test with only single run. I expected that using of `invocationCount` in `@Test` method will help with it, but was wrong. Is there any solution to invoke `@DataProvider` only once regardless on number of objects returned by provider without changing it's sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can only deal with this issue on the data provider side.

```
@DataProvider(name = "CredentialsProvider", parallel = true)
public static Object[][] credentialsProvider(Method method) { ... }

@DataProvider(name = "CredentialsProvider", parallel = true)
public static Object[][] credentialsProvider(ITestContext context) { ... }
```

In both cases you can get information from the context of the test cases which are using the data provider. In first case, for example `method.getName();` gives you the name of the @Test method. In second case, `context.getName();` gives you the name of the test case (`<test name="TestName">`) inside the test suite.

And I meant something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < login.size(); i++) {
    credentials[i] = new Object[] {login.get(i)[0], password.get(i)[0]};
    if(i > MAX_COUNT && "EXPECTED_TEST_NAME".equals(context.getName())) { break; }
}
```

Comment: I got the idea. I have refer to `ITestContext` javadoc and found `getIncludedGroups()`. So I can use your solution but refer to included in test run groups (e.g. `group = "singleInvocation"` for providing one random option) to manage data provider output. Am I right?

Comment: yes you can also use groups for this purpose but just noting thet getIncludedGroups() gives back all the groups that are included for the test run, not the current one being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Make your DataProvider accept an argument of type Method, and write your own custom annotation to handle this.  Something like:

```
@DataProvider(name = "CredentialsProvider", parallel = true)
public static Object[][] credentialsProvider(Method method) {
    //code to extract custom annotation value
    ....
}

@Test(dataProvider = "CredentialsProvider")
@RunCount(1)
public void test(String login, String password) {
....
}
```